# Magento 2 - Two scripts have method with same name, how to call one specific of them

Tags: javascript, requirejs

## Situation

The method "test" does exist two times. If I call it while both scripts are required, then only the last one is getting called e.g. the one from *test2.js*

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/web/js/test1.js**

```
function test() { alert("test 1"); }
function foo() { alert("foo"); }
```

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/web/js/test2.js**

```
function test() { alert("test 2"); }
function bar() { alert("bar"); }
```

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml**

```
<script>
    require(['Company_Test/js/test1', 'Company_Test/js/test2'], function() {
        test();
        foo();
        bar();
    });
</script>
```

---

### Output:

```
test2
foo
bar
```

---

Is there a way to only call the test method of `test1.js` without having to change the order of the dependencies?

I tried this:

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml**

```
<script>
    require(['Company_Test/js/test1', 'Company_Test/js/test2'], function(test1, test2) {
        test1.test();
        foo();
        bar();
    });
</script>
```

But I get:

```
contacts:2964 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your js files should be decorated as [AMD module](https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd), basically wrap them in a define function:

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/web/js/test1.js**

```
define(function () {
    return {
        test: function () {
            alert('test 1')
        },
        foo: function () {
            alert('foo')
        }
    }
});
```

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/web/js/test2.js**

```
define(function () {
    return {
        test: function () {
            alert('test 2')
        },
        bar: function () {
            alert('bar')
        }
    }
});
```

Now your modules can be used correctly and you can call every function you defined like this:

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml**

```
<script>
    require(['Company_Test/js/test1', 'Company_Test/js/test2'], function(test1, test2) {
        test1.test();
        test1.foo();
        test2.bar();
    });
</script>
```